# DQL query for getting specific columns from the table

Tags: arrays, doctrine, dql

I had created the following table method in order to extract some specific table columns to allow later comparison to values stored on arrays:

```
public function findAllComposedExcelColumns()
  {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('p.branch_code, p.state_id, p.state_description, p.account, p.client_name')
        ->from('Process p');

    return ($q->fetchArray());
  }
```

But when I print an element of the retrieved array, it has also the property **id** which a don't need.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [branch_code] => ... [state_id] => ... [state_description] => ... [account] => ... [client_name] => ... ) )
```

Why the `id` is also appearing on the results? There is any way to remove it?

Comment: If you don't need it, don't use it. There is always a lot of information sent when Doctrine processes the query and sends back results. I assume you are going to loop through the result so if the id is not needed, leave it out in your loop.

Comment: @DrColossos The problem is thar

Answer (score 0):

Try hydrating with HYDRATE_SCALAR - it might give you what you want.

Eg.

```
public function findAllComposedExcelColumns()
  {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('p.branch_code, p.state_id, p.state_description, p.account, p.client_name')
        ->from('Process p');
    $output = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
    return $output;
  }
```

**edit:**

note that this will also change your array keys,

eg from ['branch_code'] to ['p_branch_code']

using this type of hydration method is also not ideal when there are related records.

All in all, the above achieves your goal for *this* scenario.  However, I would agree with DrColossos that it is better to simply loop over and ignore the data you don't want.